# jascript angular for loop executed after the promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, promise

I have a problem with promises and for loop. The following code is not executed sequentially:

```
secondQuery.find().then(function(results) {
            alert("2") 
            for (var i in results) {
                (function(index){
                    var object = results[index];
                    var item_id = results[index].id;
                    var status = object.get("status");
                    var event_id = object.get("event_id");
                    var user_id = object.get("user_id");
                    var user_id_name = object.get("user_id_name");


                    var thumbimageurl = "";
                    var nFacebookFriends = 0;
                    var nInstagramFollowers = 0;
                    var nTwitterFollowers = 0;  

                    var query2 = new Parse.Query(User)
                    query2.equalTo("username",user_id)
                    return query2.first({
                        success: function(object) {
                            alert("3")
                            var thumbfile = object.get("thumb");
                            thumbimageurl = thumbfile.url();
                            nFacebookFriends = object.get('nFacebookFriends');
                            nInstagramFollowers = object.get('nInstagramFollowers');
                            nTwitterFollowers = object.get('nTwitterFollowers'); 
                        }
                    }).then(function(){
                        alert("4")
                        requests.push({
                            'thumb': thumbimageurl,
                            'item_id':item_id,
                            'status':status,
                            'event_id':event_id,
                            'user_id':user_id,
                            'user_id_name':user_id_name,
                            'nFacebookFriends':nFacebookFriends,
                            'nInstagramFollowers':nInstagramFollowers,
                            'nTwitterFollowers':nTwitterFollowers
                        })
                    })
                })(i)
            }
        }).then(function(){
                    alert('end')
                        $scope.requests = requests;
                        $localStorage.requests = requests;
                      //  alert(JSON.stringify(requests))
        })
```

After the "2" alert instead of a cycle of "3" and "4" I got directly "end". Is there a way to force the for loop to be executed before the next promise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how asynchronous calls happen. What happens here is that the outermost block (`secondQuery.find().then...`) is executed, and when the promise returns, the callback is executed synchronously (all the iterations of the loop fire different asynchronous calls), and then exits, to execute the `then` block that contains `alert('end')`; because in your code, I observe that `query2.first` is an asynchronous call, which must not return before the `end` block is called.

if you want the `end` block to come after the `3` and `4`, you will have to chain it to them. That's the only way to guarantee the sequence you desire. Or you can look up [promise.all()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) (if your library uses bluebird) or [promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (es6)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a chain of promise and Each of it is pending on previous promise in the chain.  so inside each iteration of for loop  you can keep adding `promises` to the `promise chain`.

Note:  But i have an issue @ `query2.first`  this returns a promise  and also it callback ?  in that case, i dont know what happens with the callback part.

```
    secondQuery.find().then(function(results) {
    alert("2");

    // We will create a chain of promises here,
    // Each of it is pending on previouse promise in the chain
    var promise = Promise.resolve();

    for (var i in results) {
        (function(index) {                    
            promise = promise.then(function() {                       
                var object = results[index];
                var item_id = results[index].id;
                var status = object.get("status");
                var event_id = object.get("event_id");
                var user_id = object.get("user_id");
                var user_id_name = object.get("user_id_name");


                var thumbimageurl = "";
                var nFacebookFriends = 0;
                var nInstagramFollowers = 0;
                var nTwitterFollowers = 0;  

                var query2 = new Parse.Query(User);
                query2.equalTo("username",user_id);

                //I am not very sure about this,  this return a promise also there is a callback
                //So When callback hits is out of this scope
                return query2.first({
                    success: function(object) {
                        alert("3")
                        var thumbfile = object.get("thumb");
                        thumbimageurl = thumbfile.url();
                        nFacebookFriends = object.get('nFacebookFriends');
                        nInstagramFollowers = object.get('nInstagramFollowers');
                        nTwitterFollowers = object.get('nTwitterFollowers'); 
                    }
                })
            })
            .then(function() {
                alert("4");
                requests.push({
                    'thumb': thumbimageurl,
                    'item_id':item_id,
                    'status':status,
                    'event_id':event_id,
                    'user_id':user_id,
                    'user_id_name':user_id_name,
                    'nFacebookFriends':nFacebookFriends,
                    'nInstagramFollowers':nInstagramFollowers,
                    'nTwitterFollowers':nTwitterFollowers
                })
            })
        })(i)
    }

    return promise;
})
.then(function(){
    alert('end');
    $scope.requests = requests;
    $localStorage.requests = requests;
    //  alert(JSON.stringify(requests))
})
```